# Matrix with a prime $A'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I can't find this over the Internet: what does a matrix with a prime $A'$ mean?

I found this in an exercise, this is in basic linear algebra.

Comment: Look through your text. It might mean another matrix, or it could mean the transpose. The notation is not standard. So your textbook author has something specific in mind.

Comment: It really is quite contextual. Sometimes $A^{\prime}$ is taken to mean the transpose of the matrix.

Comment: It could also just denote another matrix, or it could be denoting a change of basis making a matrix from A to A'.

Comment: If you state the exercise, it will probably make the meaning evident.

Comment: In Matlab (and Octave) programming language notation, A' is the inverse of A.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, this means adjoint or hermitian conjugate: $A^\dagger$